# Google cloud compute - forward http to https

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm on google cloud compute engine with a go webserver (no apache or nginx).   I want to forward all http requests to https.  My go code has `ListenAndServe` on port 8080 and the binary runs on port 3000 as https.  This was accomplished using below.

> gcloud compute forwarding-rules create pgurus --global --address
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx --ip-protocol TCP --ports=3000 --target-http-proxy
>   TARGET_HTTP_PROXY

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can send back a `301` response when you receive an HTTP request. Google Cloud load balancer will set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header with either the value HTTP or HTTPS. See this answer for details: 
 https://serverfault.com/a/735223

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated. The new URL
>   should be provided in the Location field included with the response.